# Background under menu

Tags: html, css

My client wants to put a  black background under the top navigation bar. it can be at
http://seasonlawn.com/CellularSolutionsHTML/catalog.html
can someone please help me how to code this in css

Comment: under ul ...the image is failed to load

Comment: im not sure what you mean can you explain? im only 16 i have no experience in this i taught myself all i know.

Comment: its firebug check link in answer

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that image you included(in `.categorymenus ul`) is failed to include/load
you can sue [**firebug**](https://getfirebug.com/) to check

[image]

what you need to do is include proper path everything else is ok

[image]

there also many image failed to load also

[image]

Comment: What debugger are you using? i tried that earlier with my eror console on safari it never showed that

Comment: NullPointer, points you in opposite direction of null.

Answer (score 2):

open the `default.css` file in a text editor and change the following code:

```
#headertop {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1130px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    background: url("../images/topnav-rep.png") repeat-x left top transparent;
    height: 32px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

to the

```
#headertop {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1130px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    background: #000000;
    height: 32px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Currently the problem is `../images/topnav-rep.png` image is not accesible. In the above line we are removing the image and making the background color for `#headertop` element black (hex -> #000000).

Comment: Thanks all so much ive been looking for ever didnt even think checking the links in my .css  it was weird because it was working locally on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Add Background color to this class

```
#main-nav .categorymenus{background-color:#000;}
.categorymenus ul{here background image failed to load check this once}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="categorymenus" style="display: block;background: url("http://www.lacovachamiami.com/images/layout/lightBackgound.png") repeat ;">
```